# Write $z = -1 + i$ as a complex number in polar form.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Write $z = -1 + i$ as a  complex number in polar form.

Answer: $|z|= \sqrt{(-1)^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{2}$ and  $\arg(z) = \tan^{-1} (1/(-1)) = \pi - (\pi/4) = \frac{3\pi}{4} $

My question is - how did $\tan^{-1} (1/(-1))$ turn into $\pi - \pi/4$? I understand that by using inverse tan some answers may be very complicated or just impossible, but what I don't understand is how they implemented pi into an equation.

Comment: How familiar are you with radians? Or would you have preferred to do the angle in degrees? (Besides, I don't think you should rely too much on $\tan^{-1}$ here, just draw the damn thing and see immediately what the angle must be. Then do the $\tan^{-1}$ to see how it works, so you can use it when you _actually_ need it.)

Comment: since it needs to be in polar form, I guess radians? I did use radians last year for advanced trigonometry last year. (answer to your suggestion - It's not actually my answer, it is the answer given by the New Zealand Mathematics Department, so I'm trying to follow the path that seems to be the safest which is to just listen to their answer and try and understand it.

Comment: Draw a picture of $z$ first (Argand diagram). You see that $z$ is in the second quadrant. The obtuse counter-clockwise angle it makes with the positive real axis (its argument) is $\pi$ minus the acute angle it makes with the negative real axis. Find that acute angle using $\tan^{-1}$, ignoring the signs on the components of $z$. In finding the polar form, simply avoid the inverse tan of angles greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$, just look at the geometry

Answer (score 3):

You must be cautious when using the $\arctan$ function for computing the arguments. Indeed:

$$\tan(x)=\tan(x+\pi)=\tan(x+k\pi)$$

where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. You can verify it easily by drawing the $x \mapsto \tan(x)$ function:

[image: tan(x)]

This is a periodical function which period is $\pi$. You can also verify it with the definition of $\tan(x)$:

$$\tan(x + k \pi) = \frac{\sin(x + k\pi)}{\cos(x + k\pi)} = \frac{\sin(x)\cos(k\pi) + \cos(x)\sin(k\pi)}{\cos(x) \cos (k\pi) + \sin(x) \sin(k\pi)}$$
$$ = \frac{(-1)^k \sin(x) + 0}{(-1)^k \cos(x) + 0} = \tan(x)$$

You know that:

$$\tan(\pi/4)=1 \Longleftrightarrow \tan(-\pi/4) = -1$$

So your answer may be $-\pi/4$, but also $k\pi-\pi/4$.

but when imaging the $z = -1 + i$ number on the complex plane, you see that your number is in the **second quadrant**. Thus, as you can see it on the picture below, the answer will be $\pi -\pi/4$ and not just $-\pi/4$.

[image: geogebra]

---

Note that the function $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ will always give you a **single value**. For instance, $\arctan(-1) = -\pi/4$ is **always true**. However, $f(z) = \arg(z)$ can take different forms. Be carefull with that. The statement "$\arctan(1/-1) = \pi - \pi/4$" is not formally correct, even if $\arg(-1+i) = \pi - \pi/4$ is.

[image: geogebra 2]

Comment: I get the ending part of your answer, but I'm having trouble comprehending how tan(x)=tan(x+π)=tan(x+kπ)

Comment: Ok, I'll add the $f(x) = \tan(x)$ function to my post to help

Comment: I added the graph + the analytical proof

Comment: Hint: For which values is $\tan x$ positive?  Also, you can prove the the statement that Albert gave is true by using the identity $\tan (x + y) = \dfrac {\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}$ with $y = \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\arctan$ maps $\Bbb R$ to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ Hence the two consecutive equalities in "the answer given by the New Zealand Mathematics Department" are wrong:

- $\arctan(-1)$ is not $\frac{3\pi}4$ but $-\frac\pi4,$ hence
- $\arg z\ne\arctan(-1)$ since (as we shall see) $\arg z=\frac{3\pi}4.$

However, we know at least that
$$\bmod\pi,\quad\arg z\equiv\arctan(-1)=-\frac\pi4.$$
To know the exact value (i.e. $\bmod{2\pi}$), just look at the sign of

- either $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ (which is $<0$ hence $\arg z\in(\pi/2,3\pi/2)\bmod{2\pi}$)
- or $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ (which is $>0$ hence $\arg z\in(0,\pi)\bmod{2\pi}$).

This (finally!) gives you the result ($\frac{3\pi}4$). But better use the simpler method hinted by Arthur and Paul in their comments.

Answer (score 0):

The principal angle for $\arctan (-1)$ is $-\dfrac {\pi}{4}$, but because $\tan x$ is negative in two quadrants (the second and the fourth), we would have two angles that share this value - $\dfrac {3 \pi}{4}$ and $\dfrac {7 \pi}{4}$.

Plotting $-1+i$ with the real numbers on the $x$ axis and imaginary numbers on the $y$ axis, this number is in the second quadrant, so we subtract $\dfrac {\pi}{4}$ from $\pi$ (or add $-\dfrac {\pi}{4}$ to $\pi$) to get $\dfrac {3 \pi}{4}$.  This gives us $\cos \frac {3 \pi}{4} + i \sin \frac {3 \pi}{4}$ or $e^{\frac {3 \pi i}{4}}$ as the polar representation of $-1 + i$.

(Incidentally, $\frac {7 \pi}{4}$ will give us the representation of $-1-i$, via $\cos \frac {7 \pi}{4} + i \sin \frac {7 \pi}{4}$ or $e^{\frac {7 \pi i}{4}}$.)